# Estructura de archivo JSON

Tags: javascript, android, json

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, he creado un script en google appscript que me exporta data de google sheets a un aplicativo web JSON,con este formato:

```
[{"name":"arevalo","clave":1,"sede":"Centro"}, 
 {"name":"saldaña","clave":4321,"sede":"Norte"}, 
 {"name":"flores","clave":1,"sede":"Norte"}, 
 {"name":"cueva","clave":1,"sede":"Este"}]
```

Lo que quiero es que se exporte con el siguiente formato

```
**{"Sheet1":**[{"name":"arevalo","clave":1,"sede":"Centro"},
  {"name":"saldaña","clave":4321,"sede":"Norte"}, 
  {"name":"flores","clave":1,"sede":"Norte"}, 
  {"name":"cueva","clave":1,"sede":"Este"}]**}**
```

Es decir anteponer en la estructura el nombre de la hoja. Soy nuevo en esto espero me puedan ayudar. Dejo el codigo del appscript

```js
function convertSheet2JsonText(sheet,super) {
  // first line(title)
  var colStartIndex = 1;
  var rowNum = 1;
  var firstRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var firstRowValues = firstRange.getValues();
  var titleColumns = firstRowValues[0];

  // after the second line(data)
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var rowValues = [];
  for(var rowIndex=2; rowIndex<=lastRow; rowIndex++) {
    var colStartIndex = 1;
    var rowNum = 1;
    var range = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, colStartIndex, rowNum, sheet.getLastColumn());
    var values = range.getValues();
    
    if (values[0][0]==super){
          
    rowValues.push(values[0]);
      
    }
  
  }
```

Gracias

Comment: En la misma función de GAS puedes hacer esto: `var json={}; json["Sheet1"] = elArray;` o bien:  `json.Sheet1 = elArray;` o si el nombre de la hoja estuviera en una variable: `json[varSheet] = elArray;`

Answer (score -1):

Solo asignale el valor a una nueva variable con el objeto y el arreglo

Te dejo el codigo:

```js
var ArrayJSON = [{"name":"arevalo","clave":1,"sede":"Centro"}, 
 {"name":"saldaña","clave":4321,"sede":"Norte"}, 
 {"name":"flores","clave":1,"sede":"Norte"}, 
 {"name":"cueva","clave":1,"sede":"Este"}];

var Nuevo = {"Sheet1":ArrayJSON}

console.log(Nuevo)
```